# How to customise order of Intentions menu

Tags: java, intellij-idea

As of IDEA 2018.2 (macOS), the order in which options in the *alt+Enter* (Intentions) menu appear has changed. To me, the order is now less logical and relevant to the current context than it was before. Is it possible to change the order?

For example, given a JUnit class ***MyClassTest*** in a Java project, hitting *alt+Enter* on the class name previously gave ***Run 'MyClassTest'*** as the first option. That option is now 4th in the menu, and the first is ***'Create Subclass'***, which to me is simply not relevant.

[image]

Comment: Good question, I don't know if it is possible. As a side note, I always run tests with the direct shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + F10 for me), you have the shortcut in your picture.

Comment: Yes, perhaps I just need to adjust my habits :) Still, the customisation would be cool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Customizing the order of intention actions is currently not possible in IntelliJ IDEA. There is an open feature request you can vote for:

- [IDEA-88512](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88512)

`Run` | `Run...` would be a better alternative for your specific use case. You can check/change the shortcut for this action [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs4pn.png). Or just use the shortcut shown in the intention actions menu to run or debug your tests.

Comment: Great, something I can vote for. I am not the only one then :)